# How to use 100's of different .gif images in Android Studio

Tags: android

I've 100's of .gif images to be used in a android application that I'm trying to build. Can any one suggest me how should I minimize their size. And should I place them in drawable directory.

Answer (score 0):

Google play has a limit on APK size which can be uploaded to playstore(if I am not wrong its 100Mb), so having so many .gif files inside application drawable folder will not be a solution.

Best solution I could think of right now is via Dynamic asset delivery by google play.

Please go through below for more info on asset delivery

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery

Comment: My application needs to work in offline mode. It don't required Internet connection. So, can these asset delivery works in it??

Comment: These will be delivered at the time on installing from play store.